# Minify a file during rendering in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rendering, minify

I am working on a project in angularJs and I am unable to think of a way in which I minifiy a file during rendering. Is there any way in javascript or angular ? Please help I am a newbie

Answer (score 1):

you have to minimify before, for this you can use plenty of tools online :

https://jscompress.com/

https://javascript-minifier.com/

Use js minimify tool directly with node js :

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

Use a task runner like gulp or grunt with minimify plugin:

http://gruntjs.com/

http://gulpjs.com/

or use webpack to bundle and minimify your website or application:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/

Comment: is there any other way apart from online tools ?

Comment: All brilliant tools! If you need something with an interface, you can download [Koala](http://koala-app.com/).

Comment: yeah uglify2 is pretty good, you just have to install node&npm install uglify with 'npm install uglify-js -g' and then just do in a terminal 'uglifyjs yourFilePath' see the doc in my answer

Comment: Then use webpack, gulp, grunt, brocoli or other tool. They create automatic tasks that run with a single command line.